# Remote controlling Raspberry Pi from Windows

Tags: remote, windows

I'm wondering if I can control remotely my Raspberry Pi 3 with installed Raspbian from windows. I know I can via SSH or xrdp but those services are creating another session. I want to control what I see on my Raspberry Pi connected to TV for example turn on web browser YouTube and changing movies that everyone is watching on the TV. Something like Teamviewer perhaps?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing). It's is a graphical desktop sharing system to remotely control another computer.

If you have Raspbian Jessie or later, VNC Connect is pre-installed. To enable VNC:

Go to your Raspberry Pi > Open the application menu > Preferences > Raspberry Pi Configuration > tab Interfaces > Enable VNC

[image: Configure VNC]

If not, install VNC server manually :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install realvnc-vnc-server
```

1. Go to your Raspberry and click on the VNC server icon that appears on top
2. Click on the menu > options
3. click on users and permission and the click on the Add button
4. under type: user , in the name section, enter the pi user. Then click apply and ok
5. reboot

When you have install or enable VNC, download a VNC software like [RealVNC](https://www.realvnc.com/) and connect you to your Raspberry Pi

Comment: I've installed vncserver but now i have a problem connecting from windows10 standard username "pi" and password "raspberry" is not working "access denied"

Comment: Try to go to the screen display connected to the Pi and click on the VNC server icon that appears on top
1. Click on more --> options
2. click on users and permission and the click on the Add button
3. under type: user , in the name section, enter the pi user. Then click apply and ok
4.reboot